# Why was this "unclear" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304997/how-can-i-testfor-a-player-within-a-certain-radius) is unclear, so I flagged it as such. As far as I understand, he wants to detect players in a radius, but somehow doesn't like the radius selector or something like that. It's unclear if he wants to use something else to solve his problem (in that case he should describe the problem) or if he wants help with the selector he mentioned. The answers are also just guessing what he means.
The flag was declined without any comment. Why?

Comment: Was it declined or disputed?

Comment: It was declined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your flag was declined without comment, is because the post was found to have three "Leave Open" votes. [See review](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/238636) (I'm not sure if you can look at the review link or not).

From [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac):

> If your flag was a recommend closure flag, if it receives three "Leave Open" responses in the Close Votes queue without a single close vote, it will be marked declined.

This is why there is no reason behind the decline message, since it was an "automated" decline. That explains the "why it was declined," by *why was it declined?*  Well, the community appears to have disagreed with you that it should have been closed.  I've noticed that you seem to specialize in Minecraft and Minecraft Command questions.  You may be more educated on those types of questions where other members of the community are not.  For me, an unclear post is one that can't be comprehended.  Your reasoning for this example seems a bit more technical, and that may be why others have disagreed with you.

Comment: Should I flag it again or just leave it at only a downvote?

Comment: @Fabian your free to do what you want, but note that too many declined flags results in a temporary flagging ban.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and cast the fourth close vote on that question, and then deleted it.

Based on the users comments and your flag it's clear none of the answers addressed the askers issues, and that none of the answers were actually sure what the user was asking, which is what warrants the close vote.  Since the user is now deleted there's no way for them to ever provide that clarity, which means it'll sit around closed forever, which is why I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I was one of the 3 that voted to leave open because:

1. I interpreted the question as the OP not being totally sure if he was using the command correctly;
2. All 3 answers were similar and were upvoted, giving evidence that the question was answerable and useful;
3. The question was over 6 months old, therefore anything significantly wrong with the question should have already been picked up;
4. The user had already left the site so there is no opportunity to confirm details (remember that not everyone ticks an accepted answer).

If there was anything technically wrong with the question then it should be detailed in a comment.  This allows reviewers to check concerns.  I've rarely seen someone decline a close flag and then detail their reasoning in a comment... especially when the item has no comment stating why it should be closed.

Before the question was closed and deleted I pushed one of the OP's comments from one of the answers into the question.  It gave a little more insight into the problem, although obviously not enough.

Obviously I can't answer for the other 2 people who voted to keep the question open.